# Resize input form

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-css-modules

I'm trying to make this:
[image: image1]

But for now I have this:
[image: image2]

I don't understand how I can resize input with icon on right... I am on col-md-12...
You can look my code here:

```css
.form {
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-left: 13px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.search-field {
  padding: 10px 35px 10px 15px;
  color: #fff;
  border-color: #d4e0e0;
  border-radius: 15px;
  outline: none;
  background: #FFFFFF 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 3px 6px #0000000D;
  border: 1px solid #D4E0E0;
  width: auto;
  color: #000;
}

.search-button {
  z-index: 1;
  float: inline-end;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  margin-top: -2px;
  margin-left: -45px;
}

.search-button img {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
      <div class="list row">
        <span class="font-link-bold" style={{ fontSize: "26px" }}>
          <span class="title-card font-link-blue-bold">Mes </span>Conseils
        </span>
        <div class="button-create">
          <IconCreate />  Créer un nouveau conseil
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <span
          class="font-link"
          style={{ fontSize: "16px", color: "#657273" }}
        >
          Saisir vos mots-clés ou coller un texte :
        </span>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <form action="/" method="GET" class="form">
            <input
              type="search"
              placeholder="Search"
              class="search-field"
            />
            <button type="submit" class="search-button">
              <img src={IconLoupe} alt="" />
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
```

In my html you can see "col-md-12" and the other col-md-12 take all space... just input take an col-md-3 or 6...

Answer (score 0):

Try giving width 100% to .search-field

```
.search-field {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

It should work or you can also try giving position to your icon

```
parent{ 
  position: relative;
}
child{ 
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Its works but my button is too long...  and if i resize windows is not correctly placed...

Comment: @PouneyDesign For that you need to add media query for different screens. Please refer - https://css-tricks.com/a-complete-guide-to-css-media-queries/